# Specialized output with for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I have an csv file and i want to get a specialized output with just typing in the ID (PIPAPNr) for a letter
for example
input = PIPAP1147

output *Roger Nadal 11.07.1993*

```
Pipapnr="PIPAP1147"
for (i in 1:nrow(Patienten)){
  if (Patienten$PIPAP.Nr.==Pipapnr)
    DOB<- (Patienten$Geburtsdatum[i])
    Name<- (Patienten$Name[i])}
```

The error is

```
In if (Patienten$PIPAP.Nr. == Pipapnr) DOB <- (Patienten$Geburtsdatum[i]) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: Please provide  a minimal working example WITH a few data records.  Second, R has scores if not hundreds of specialized functions for all sorts of database operations in many formats. Writing your own for loops is time-consuming and inefficient as the builtin functions are much more optimized and already fully debugged (well mostly!). Start by examining the base R functions which() and unique(). In the end you are going to want to look at data tables, likely, if you're in a large setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In if (Patienten$PIPAP.Nr. == Pipapnr) DOB <- (Patienten$Geburtsdatum[i]) :
> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

In this code `Pipapnr` contains just one value, however `Patienten$PIPAP.Nr.` probably contains lots of values so there are many comparisons and only the first is used.

That is the explanation of the error message. Probably you wanted the `if`clause to read as `if (Patienten$PIPAP.Nr.[i]==Pipapnr) ...`

Still, John Garland is right in his comment, that these things can be handled more elegantly in R. Maybe something like `which(Patienten$PIPAP.Nr.==Pipapnr`?

As your Code reads German, maybe you are interested in the German R forum at http://forum.r-statistik.de ?